# FullCalendar (momentJS) delta.duration().days() is not a function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

I am using the delta variable to access the day and time of the calendar on which it was selected. I cannot access the delta moment object, it indicates that it is not a function.

I think the error is in the order of the scripts.

```js
<script src='/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'><\/script>
<script src='/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js'></script>
<script //src='/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='/fullcalendar-3.10.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/fullcalendar-3.10.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='/fullcalendar-3.10.0/locale/es.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.multiselect.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.multiselect.es.js'></script>

eventDrop: function(event,delta, refertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view){
   $.get('<?php echo url_for("agenda/getEvento");?>/id/'+event.id+'/day_delta/'+delta.date()+'/minute_delta/'+delta.duration().minutes()+'/all_day/'+(allDay?1:0)
},
```

Comment: As per the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventDrop), `delta` is a [Duration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/moment-duration) object, not a regular momentJS object. P.S. For fullCalendar 3.x you really are supposed to use jQuery 2.x or above. You might run into problems using 1.x.

Comment: You are wrong, if you look at the documentation you will see that this functionality is provided by MomentJS, a third-party open-source library. [link] https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/moment-duration

Comment: "this functionality is provided by MomentJS"...I know that. I never said it wasn't. The link you've given me is the same one I gave to you in my comment! But a Duration object is not the same as a Moment object, that was my point. A Duration object doesn't have a `date()` function, or a `duration()` function, which is likely the reason for your error. It already _is_ a duration, so `delta.minutes()` should work.

Comment: Also, the `delta` does not contain "the day and time of the calendar on which it was selected", as you've said in your question that you're expecting it to. The documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventDrop) says clearly that it is a Duration which represents "the amount of time the event was moved by". This is a different piece of data. If you want to know the date/time on which the event was dropped, you can just check `event.start`.